# Is there any issue using the same postgresql database for two different servers?

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, jboss, database-server

I am using postgres database which is accessed by jboss and tomcat server. 
My server accidentally restarted and then postgres service was not showing in the services list.
When I tried to open postgres local host server using pgadminIII it showed following error:

```
Server doesn't listen
The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
If you encounter this message, please check if the server you're trying to contact is actually running PostgreSQL on the given port. Test if you have network connectivity from your client to the server host using ping or equivalent tools. Is your network / VPN / SSH tunnel / firewall configured correctly? 
For security reasons, PostgreSQL does not listen on all available IP addresses on the server machine initially. In order to access the server over the network, you need to enable listening on the address first. 
For PostgreSQL servers starting with version 8.0, this is controlled using the "listen_addresses" parameter in the postgresql.conf file. Here, you can enter a list of IP addresses the server should listen on, or simply use '*' to listen on all available IP addresses. For earlier servers (Version 7.3 or 7.4), you'll need to set the "tcpip_socket" parameter to 'true'. 
You can use the postgresql.conf editor that is built into pgAdmin III to edit the postgresql.conf configuration file. After changing this file, you need to restart the server process to make the setting effective. 
If you double-checked your configuration but still get this error message, it's still unlikely that you encounter a fatal PostgreSQL misbehaviour. You probably have some low level network connectivity problems (e.g. firewall configuration). Please check this thoroughly before reporting a bug to the PostgreSQL community.
```

Does this problem arise due to accessing same DB by two different servers?

Answer (score 0):

> My server accidentally restarted and then postgres service was not
>   showing in the services list.

You can't connect because it's not running. You can have as many clients connecting to a PostgreSQL server as your hardware can support - there is no problem with that.

Restart your PostgreSQL service. If it won't, check the logs for why. If you don't know where your PostgreSQL logs are now is a good time to find out. I can't tell you how to restart the service because you haven't said what OS you are running or how you installed PG. Check your documentation.

Comment: That doesn't really provide any more explanation. If you want more assistance you will need to start providing system level logs and the like.

Comment: I had reinstalled postgresql and it works succesfully. I just want to know why it showed the error? Will it occur again?

Comment: It wasn't running - that's why the error was reported. Other people can't explain why it wasn't running because you haven't provided any information.

Comment: umm - the parts of your server logs showing why it didn't start up?